# Programatically update store name and website name

Tags: programmatically, websites, stores

I want edit store name and website name programatically, how it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated

### For store try this

```
$storeModel = Mage::getModel('core/store_group');

//  Load by store Id:

 $storeModel->load($id);

 $storeModel->setData('name','Amit');
 $storeModel->save();
```

### For Website:

```
$websiteModel = Mage::getModel('core/website');
$websiteModel->load($WebsiteId);
$websiteModel->setData('name','MYStoreWebsite');
$websiteModel->save();
```

You can easily do it by shell script. Create a file **update.php** in your Magento directory and add the following code:

```
require "YourMagentoDirPath/app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

$storeModel = Mage::getModel('core/store_group');

//  Load by store Id:
$storeModel->load($id);

$storeModel->setData('name','Amit');
$storeModel->save();

$websiteModel = Mage::getModel('core/website');
$websiteModel->load($WebsiteId);
$websiteModel->setData('name','MYStoreWebsite');
$websiteModel->save();
```

Comment: Website and store view name is change but store name is not changing.

Comment: please  check now,it works

Comment: Yes it works correctly....